# how to create Gantt Chart view on Iphone sreen

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, graphing, gantt-chart

I wonder how to create Gantt Chart view or (Matrix table on PC )on Iphone sreen.

see demo here http://www.projectwizards.net/en/merlin-iphone

you know the Iphone's screen is very small(320x480),  the Gantt Chart view is large.

what API or Framework do I need to use?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView should be able to handle this.  You can feed it tiles, each the size of an hour or day or week or whatever the horizontal axis of your Gantt chart is.